# how do you create a bitmap from a gradient stop collection c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmap

I am trying to get a bitmap from a GradientStopCollection, so far I have been able to create a the GradientStopCollection with the following code.

```
public GradientStopCollection GradientColor(Color SelectedColor)
{
    GradientStopCollection CGbrush = new GradientStopCollection(2);
    CGbrush.Add(new GradientStop(SelectedColor, 0));
    CGbrush.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 1));

    return CGbrush;
}
```

I have tried to create a bit a copple time but so far none are successful.
If anyone has any ideas I would be happy to hear them,
Thanks :)

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a LinearGradientBrush and fill e.g. a Rectangle with it? A bitmap doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: I could convert it to a LinearGradientBrush but I am trying to make it into a bit map to get its color from a certain point. ```CGbrush.Add(new GradientStop(SelectedColor, 0)); 
CGbrush.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 1));```

Comment: Creating such a bitmap would mean to do a lot of interpolations between the two colors. You could as well do that on the fly for a certain point without a bitmap.